Error: "Argument of type 'PublicKey' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Provider'" when running Anchor test in Solana program
I'm working on a Solana program using the Anchor framework, and I'm trying to run a test script that interacts with the treasury_toolkit program I created. However, when I run npx tsc --noEmit to compile my TypeScript test file, I keep getting the following error:
error TS2345: Argument of type 'PublicKey' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Provider'. Property 'connection' is missing in type 'PublicKey' but required in type 'Provider'.
Here’s the relevant part of my code that seems to be causing the problem:
const program = new Program<TreasuryToolkit>(
  idl as TreasuryToolkit,
  programId,
  provider // Error points to this line
);

I've double-checked that the IDL file and program ID are correct, and the provider is being set using AnchorProvider.local().
Steps I've tried:

Ensured that the IDL path and the program ID are correct.
Checked the types in @coral-xyz/anchor and web3.js but can't seem to
resolve this mismatch.

Environment:

Node.js version: v20.18.0
Anchor version: anchor-cli 0.30.1
Solana CLI version: solana-cli 1.18.25
TypeScript version: Version 4.8.4

Can someone please help me understand why this type mismatch is happening and how I can fix it? Is there something wrong with how I'm passing the PublicKey or the provider?

Defining a program is different from anchor version 0.30.0 and above. You don't need to include the programId in the constructor.
import * as idl from "./idl/spl_staking.json";
import type { SplStaking } from "./types/spl_staking";

const program = new anchor.Program(idl as unknown as SplStaking, provider);

ref -> https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/issues/2914#issuecomment-2084897026
example with soundwork-sdk -> https://github.com/SoundWorkLabs/soundwork-sdk/blob/af73808541f3ca7df04976cbca8a5854e19f8fa2/src/soundwork-list/sdk.ts#L49-L52
